# Using NgFor in Mat-table in Angular

Tags: angular, mat-table

Here in my code, I am able to iterate no. of tables, but the problem is that column no. and its name remains the same for all tables that are iterated.
How can I fix it?

```html
    <div class="mat-table {{defaultView == 'table' ? 'mat-table-lg' : 'mat-table-sm'}}" data-automation-attribute="div-results">
       <mat-table #table *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSources let Ind = index" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>                  
          <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumnss let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
            <mat-header-cell class="tableHeader" style="font-weight: bold" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
              {{ columnNames[colIndex] }}  
             
            </mat-header-cell>     
            <mat-header-cell class="tableHeader" style="font-weight: bold" *matHeaderCellDef >
                <mat-cell *matRowDef ><input matInput placeholder="Item Code" >   </mat-cell>    
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef> {{colIndex}}</mat-cell>
              </mat-header-cell>         
          
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: right" contenteditable="true"
              ><label>{{element[disCol]}}</label>
              </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnss"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnss;">             
          </mat-row>
        </mat-table><br>
    
      </div>
```

Comment: If you want index then use one variable with autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i
```

Comment: Duplicate column definition name provided: "id,country_id,name,type,status".
    at getTableDuplicateColumnNameError (table.es5.js:680)
Its showing above error.